# Using SwiftUI's new Grid API in iOS 16 dynamically to layout an unknown # of views of unequal sizes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16

[This post](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-grid/) goes into great detail of SwiftUI's new Grid view in iOS 16, however it uses static examples.  I've created a demo project below to show an example, in my use case I do not know the exact number or length of the strings in data.  Is it possible to use this new Grid API to layout these views in a way that will evenly distribute them, i.e. construct my code so that, e.g. if 3 view's do not fit, it will only make 2 columns and push the 3rd view to the next row so that they won't overlap?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var data = [
    "Beatles",
    "Pearl Jam",
    "REM",
    "Guns n Roses",
    "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
    "No Doubt",
    "Nirvana",
    "Tom Petty and the Heart Breakers",
    "The Eagles"
   
    ]
    

    var body: some View {
        
        Grid() {
            GridRow {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { bandName in
                    Text(bandName)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                }
            }
            
        
        }
        
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Current implementation only has a single GridRow - which forces all text views into a single row. A Grid might be the incorrect way to conceptualise this unless you really want to have a fixed grid layout where number of columns in the whole grid is determined by max size of a cell. Have a look at this post for inspiration: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/flexible-swiftui/

Comment: Thanks @mani I actually am using this exact FlexibleView right now, but found it buggy in iOS 16 - bindings don't seem to work well, i.e. passing a `hasBeenTapped` bool to the FlexibleView's subview - the subView doesn't receive the change, which is why I was trying to refactor using the new grid API.

Comment: Your current implementation has only one `GridRow` and all `Text` is displayed in the single row. Place `GridRow` inside the `ForEach` loop - this will place each cell in its own row. Ask a new question on StackOverflow regarding the bug you mentioned `hasBeenTapped`. But at a high level, you need to render each text view, get its width, and then decide how many rows you will need. The Grid and GridRow API AFAIK is for showing fixed size grids, but it seems like a fixed size grid is not what you actually want.